# When renewing provisioning profiles, I must also renew the push (APN) certificates?

Tags: ios

If my provisioning profiles expired and I renew them, do I also need to renew the certificates used for push notifications? Or I can keep using the old ones as long as they are valid?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read this http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/30/renewing-provisioning-profiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to renew the Push Notification certificates until they expire. Their expiry is not linked to the provisioning profiles that [indirectly] reference them.